# Vlookup Comparing 2 columns

Tags: excel, vlookup

`=VLOOKUP(A2,C2:C238,2,FALSE)` I have attached an image of my excel file and the 2 columns to be compared . I have written this formula but its throwing error.Thanks IN advance for helping

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want to check if there is a match. Use the MATCH function instead.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to reference the 2nd column in a table range that only has 1 column

Try using:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,C2:C238,1,FALSE)
```

You might also want to make the range constant so use

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$C$2:$C$238,1,FALSE)
```

Or if the column you're trying to return is column `D` then you'll need to use

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,C2:D238,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks For the response i have tried both  it but i end of getting error #N/A.

Comment: If it's not found it'll return `#N/A`

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply trying to determine if the value of `A2` exists in `C2` then all you need to do is change your formula to the following:

```
=vlookup(A2, $C$2:$C$238,1,FALSE)
```

This formula will return the value of `A2` if there is a match and `#N/A` if there is no match. If you want to make it look a little nicer you can use the following:

```
=if(iserror(vlookup(A2, $C$2:$C$238,1,FALSE))=FALSE,"Match exists","No match exists")
```

This basically just gives you the option to change the result value by changing the text within the quotes.